# Correlation between two hash values

Tags: algorithm, hash, correlation

If I have code like

```
// CODE 1
int x = 0;
int z = x + 2;
```

and

```
// CODE 2 
int x = 0;
int y = x + 2;


// CODE 3
string m = "";
string h = m + "hello";
```

If I applied hash function to the 3 pieces of code as string hashing for the 2 lines in each piece.

Is there anything I could perform on the hash values to conclude that CODE 2  and CODE 1 are similar to each other more than CODE 1 and CODE3 ?

is there any function or something that Can tell that the correlation between pieces of code is larger than other pieces from their hash values only ?

the hash I'm talking about is md5

Comment: What hash? Different hash functions have different properties. If you're talking about a cryptographic hash, then no, they are designed in such a way that gaining this information is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the hint... I updated the post. I'm a bit new to this area

Comment: MD5 is a cryptographic hash. A single bit change in the input completely changes the output, so working backwards like this is impossible.

Comment: thank you, post ur comment as answer to approve it

Comment: @Phylogenesis correct explanation, bad example. MD5 is already cracked.

Comment: @Paul MD5 has been (drastically) weakened in certain ways. None of which are really applicable to this situation (the best known preimage attack is 2^123.4 or so).